# Which way can I achieve the hottest cup?

Tags: temperature

Regarding drip coffee maker:

Is my coffee the HOTTEST immediately after the brewing cycle is done or sitting on the burner/plate for awhile?

I’m wondering by me letting the completed cycle sit for 15 minutes or so before pourers a cup am I cooling the coffee down or helping it to get hotter.

Thank you 
Mary

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this depends on your machine, but it is easily tested. The water should be hottest while dripping, but while it passes the filter, it'll cool down, so at what temperature it lands in the pot can only be measured, or tasted.

Regardless of temperature, letting coffee sit after brewing is never recommended since it changes flavor (and not for the better).